# Do not rerun previous tasks in Prefect

Tags: python, automation, directed-acyclic-graphs, prefect

How can I tell Prefect, to not rerun all previous tasks in DAG?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Targets](https://docs.prefect.io/core/idioms/targets.html) will get you where you want to go. From the docs:

> Targets in Prefect are templatable location strings that are used to check for the existence of a task Result. This is useful in cases where you might want a task to only write data to a location once or merely not rerun if some piece of data is present. If a result exists at that location then the task run will enter a cached state.

In your task decorator just add a target like so:

```
@task(result=LocalResult(), target="{task_name}-{today}")
```